# Geofencing with a SQL

Tags: sql, geofencing

I need to return a selection of data to a user based on the users location. For example a list of pubs in a certain radius of the user. The list of pubs is held on a SQL database.

I don't want to pull all the records into my application and then work out the correct results to the user. Hopefully this dataset would be large. Preferably I would want to use a SQL query and only return the required data to my user.

Comment: What have you tried? What does you database look like for the storage of location details?

Comment: What database system are you using? How do you store geo data for users and pubs?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet I'm finding the problem difficult to think about and Google isn't providing the information I need. The database I'm using is PosGres. The location will be longitude, latitude for both the pub and user

Comment: @JeffFinn If you're using Postgresql you might want to install the [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) extension that enables geographic functions. If you do that you can make queries of the type _get all entities with coordinates within a given radius of of this coordinate_ quite easily.